# Are there aspect ratio frame guides?

Tags: animation, camera

I don't want to change the output resolution, I would like it to remain 16:9 in the render. However I would like to film my scene with frame guides in 2:40:1 aspect ratio.

Is this possible?

Sorry if this has been asked before searched and found nothing on frame guides.

Comment: The frame guides are shown in the Camera's _Object Data Property_ under _Composition Guides_ but AFAIK it's not possible to customize the guides.

Comment: Yeah is a bummer, decided to customise the "safe areas" margin to where about 2:40:1 would be, just for now anyway. Blender missing a trick there